# Sorting Messages loaded locally and using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, date

I'm running into a problem sorting what I refer to as "messages"; some of which are in the HTML doc and some others using Ajax.  It doesn't always sort the messages (by date) and if refreshing the page, it doesn't sort at all and displays in the order they were loaded.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  I'm by no means very experienced with Javascript.  I'll happily provide more information if required.

HTML and Javascript:

```
 <section id="all messages">
    <!-- Local messages go here -->
    <div id="local-messages">
        <!-- Example of a local message with a date data attribute -->      
        <div class="message" data-date="2023-11-17">
            <div class="panel panel-success mrgn-bttm-xl">
                <header class="panel-heading">
                    <h5 class="panel-title">Local Post #1<span class="pull-right">Posted: 2023-11-17</span></h5>
                </header>
                <div class="panel-body mrgn-lft-md mrgn-rght-md">                                                                    
                    <p>Local Message Content 1.</p>
                </div>                   
            </div>                                                 
        </div>

        <div class="message" data-date="2023-11-10">
            <div class="panel panel-success mrgn-bttm-xl">
                <header class="panel-heading">
                    <h5 class="panel-title">Local Post #2<span class="pull-right">Posted: 2023-11-10</span></h5>
                </header>
                <div class="panel-body mrgn-lft-md mrgn-rght-md">                                                                    
                    <p>Local Message Content 2</p>
                </div>                   
           </div>
       </div>

       <div class="message" data-date="2023-11-01">
           <div class="panel panel-success mrgn-bttm-xl">
               <header class="panel-heading">
                   <h5 class="panel-title">Local Post #3<span class="pull-right">Posted: 2023-11-01</span></h5>
               </header>
               <div class="panel-body mrgn-lft-md mrgn-rght-md">                                                                    
                   <p>Local Message Content 3</p>
                </div>                   
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Container for regional messages; will be filled via AJAX -->
    <div id="regional-messages" class="wb-ajax" data-ajax-replace="data/path.html"></div>
    </section>

    <script src="../js/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/wet-boew.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/i18n/en.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/wet-retrigger.js"></script>
    <span id="wb-rsz" class="wb-init">&nbsp;</span>

    <script>
        $(document).on("wb-ready.wb", function() {
        var $messagesContainer = $('#all-messages');

        // Function to sort messages from newest to oldest
        function sortMessages() {
            var $messages = $messagesContainer.find('.message').toArray();
            $messages.sort(function(a, b) {
                var dateA = new Date($(a).data('date')), dateB = new Date($(b).data('date'));
                return dateB - dateA;
            });

            $.each($messages, function(index, message) {
                $messagesContainer.append(message);
            });
        }

        // Listen for the wb-contentupdated event on the regional messages container
        $('#regional-messages').on("wb-contentupdated", function(event) {
            // Wait a brief moment to ensure content is fully rendered
            setTimeout(function() {
                sortMessages();
            }, 100); // Adjust this delay as needed
        });

        // Apply the sorting logic on initial page load as well
        sortMessages();
    });
    </script>
```

I tried the code above and as mentioned, it would sort when first loaded, but if refreshed, would just load in the order the "messages" came in and not by date.